# R use list as function argument

Tags: r

I come from a C# background and try to migrate some of my time series library to R.
One of the benefits of OOP is that I can tuck away variables in a class and pass this as reference.

I read up on R environments, lists, ... and I'm still not sure about the right approach. If I would use a list then I would need to check the function argument:

exists()

(btw: Is there also a function to test for the elements in a list)

I could create a list, pass it as an argument and then write the result back in a list. But is this the right approach?

Any comments ...

Comment: I haven't used them myself, but my understanding is that specialized OOP tools (S3, S4, etc) are the way to go, rather than reinventing the wheel from the raw materials of lists and environments. For folks not maintaining complicated libraries (like me), passing in and taking out lists works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

`exists` is seldom used.  If you need it, maybe you do something wrong.

`missing` is sometimes used.

Functions sometimes, but not very often, receive lists as parameters, and often return lists.

To test whether a list `foo` has an element `bar`, use `is.null(foo$bar)`.  This is FALSE if the list has the element, TRUE otherwise.